# How to change CharacterMotor in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change the speed of the player in unity, but I can't access the CharacterMotor from another script. I searched on the interned and I found this (for C#):

```
Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0];
Player.GetComponent("CharacterMotor").
       CharacterMotorMovement.maxForwardSpeed = 6.0;
```

But this doesn't work, and I get the error:

```
Assets/Scripts/MainScript.cs(60,63): error CS1061: 
Type `UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for   
`CharacterMotorMovement' and no extension method 
`CharacterMotorMovement' of type `UnityEngine.Component' could be 
found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I've tried somethings, but I'm kinda bothered by the fact that everywhere I search offers me the same solution that doesn't work. Could anyone help me?

Comment: What error did you get? You must be more specific.

Comment: Is your player tagged as "Player". The code looking for an object tagged as "Player". If the error is null reference for player, then you don't have a player object tagged witg Player. If the error is on 2. line then there is no CharacterMotor component (script) attached to Player.

Comment: I just put the whole error. The object is tagged as player and it has a the component.

Comment: Where did you find that sample? I ask because the code posted is obviously wrong - `GetComponent(string)` is the wrong override to be using. If you used `Player.GetComponent<CharacterMotor>()....` instead then you might have more luck, as it'll return a more specifically-typed result. Ultimately though, you're asking a question that suggests you don't understand the basics of Unity's component model or of C#'s compilation/typing model, so you'd perhaps be better off starting with a simpler project.

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü: the error isn't happening because there's no such component, it's happening because [that override of `GetComponent`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) returns a base-class `Component` result, which needs to be cast to `CharacterMotor` before the class-specific properties can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turns out it was because the standard CharacterController script is written in javascript and you cannot reference the CharacterMotor class from your C# script.

Fortunately someone has already gone through the trouble of converting the CharacterMotor, FSInputController and PlatformInputController to C#.

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/charactermotor-fpsinputcontroller-platforminputcontroller-in-c.64378/

Answer (score -1):

Now as it says you must attach CharacterMovement script to the Player object.

Comment: Your advice may or may not be correct, but that won't solve the compilation error that is shown in the question.

Comment: Looks like it is not a typecasting error either. It must be like this.
Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Component' to 'UnityEngine.CharacterMovement'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?

It was not a good act to voting up a user trying to help while there is no explenation. The post has been edited.

Comment: The component is `CharacterMotor`, not `CharacterMovement`.